# Laravel how to make the program remember value of select after page refresh

Tags: php, laravel

I created 3 dropdowns with a loop, but when I change one, it will submit a form that will go to the show function of my controller. Then it returns with new parameters to the index page, but I can't get it to remember the first dropdown value.
my index page:

```
@section('main')
    <h1>Apply now!</h1>
    <h2>Select your preferences</h2>
    <form action="/applications/{{$record->id}}" method="post" id="submitForm">
        @method('put')
        @csrf
        @for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
            <p style="font-weight: bold">Choice 1</p>
            <label for="country{{$i}}">Country</label>
            <select name="country{{$i}}" id="country{{$i}}">
                <option value="%">All countries</option>
                @foreach($places_countries as $country)
                    <option value="{{$country->country->id}}  {{ (request()->country ==  $country->country->id ? 'selected' : '') }}">{{ $country->country->country }}</option>
                @endforeach
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>

            <label for="otherOption{{$i}}" hidden>what's your suggestion?</label>
            <input type="text" id="otherOption{{$i}}" hidden>

            <label for="city{{$i}}" hidden>City</label>
            <select name="city{{$i}}" id="city{{$i}}" hidden>
                <option value="%">All cities</option>
                @foreach($places_cities as $city)
                    <option value="{{$city->city->id}}">{{ $city->city->city }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <label for="organisation{{$i}}" hidden>Organisation</label>
            <select name="organisation{{$i}}" id="organisation{{$i}}" hidden>
                <option value="%">All organisations</option>
                @foreach($places_organisations as $organisation)
                    <option
                        value="{{$organisation->organisation->id}}">{{ $organisation->organisation->organisation }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        @endfor
        <br>

        <button type="submit">Submit your choices</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Student;

use App\Country;
use App\City;
use App\Organisation;
use App\Place;
use App\Record;
use Facades\App\Helpers\Json;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ApplicationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $places_countries = Place::distinct()->get(['country_id']);
        $places_cities = Place::distinct()->get(['city_id']);
        $places_organisations = Place::distinct()->get(['organisation_id']);
        $record = DB::table('records')->where('id', '1')->first();
        $result = compact('places_countries', 'places_cities', 'places_organisations', 'record');
        Json::dump($result);
        return view('student.application', $result);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return redirect('applications/');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Record  $record
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $places_countries = Place::distinct()->get(['country_id']);

        if ($request->country0 != null || $request->country1 != null || $request->country2 != null){ //if a country is chosen, set all cities of that country in dropdown
            //$places_cities = DB::table('places')->where('city_id', $id)->distinct();
            $places_cities = Place::orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
                    $query->where('city_id', '=', $id);
                });
        }else{ //if none is chosen, set all distinct cities in dropdown
            $places_cities = Place::distinct()->get(['city_id']);
        }

        if ($request->city0 != null || $request->city1 != null || $request->city2 != null){ //if a city is chosen, set all organisations of that city in dropdown
            //$places_organisations = DB::table('places')->where('organisation_id', $id)->distinct();
            $places_organisations = Place::orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
                    $query->where('organisation_id', '=', $id);
                });
        }else{//if none is chosen, set all distinct organisations in dropdown
            $places_organisations = Place::distinct()->get(['organisation_id']);
        }

        $record = DB::table('records')->where('id', '1')->first();
        $result = compact('places_countries', 'places_cities', 'places_organisations', 'record');
        Json::dump($result);
        return view('student.application', $result);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Record  $record
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Record $record)
    {
        return redirect('applications/');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Record  $record
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $record = Record::find($id);

        $preference1 = $request->country0 . " " . $request->city0 . " " . $request->organisation0;
        $preference2 = $request->country1 . " " . $request->city1 . " " . $request->organisation1;
        $preference3 = $request->country2 . " " . $request->city2 . " " . $request->organisation2;

        $record->preference1 = $preference1;
        $record->preference2 = $preference2;
        $record->preference3 = $preference3;

        $record->save();

        return response()->json([
            'type' => 'success',
            'text' => "Your preferences are submitted!",
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Record  $record
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Record $record)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If you need any more information, please let me know!

Comment: I think you shouldn't use two actions for the same form, You need to use ajax to manipulating the data or submit the form to the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that by simply using sessions, learn about Laravel session [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#introduction)

**Save data to session**

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

**Retrieve data from session**

```
// Via a request instance...
$value = $request->session()->get('key');

// Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
$value = session('key');
```